# How to calculate Log-likelihood similarity between user and item classified by tag using Mahout?

Tags: java, similarity, mahout

I have read the Mahout in action but i'm not clear about Log-likelihood similarity. I have User and Item, classified by tag tag. And now i don't known how to calculate Log-likelihood similarity between User and Item. Anyone can help me? or give me some examples or demo about this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't; you calculate similarities between users, or between items. Users and items aren't "similar" in this sense; you use a recommender to infer ratings or a strength of association, but it is not a log-likelihood similarity.

You use `LogLikelihoodSimilarity` to compute this metric, to answer your question.

Comment: Can you give me some example or resource to infer rating by using LogLikelihoodSimilarity?

Comment: As I just said, you don't do that. I think you misunderstand what the similarity metrics are for.